# I'm trying to create a triangle with java

Tags: java, geometry, height, width

//I am trying to create a basic race car in java. I made a rectangle for the body and now I am trying to make a triangle for the front. I looked online for code on creating a triangle but none of it looks like it is in the format as I have for the rectangle I have below. I got most of this code from "Video Game Programming for the Evil Genius" as a reference and now we are encouraged to create our own vehicle, but rectangles are the only shapes explained. I did copy the code from the rectangle to triangle expecting one to overlap the other, just so that I knew it worked, but it's not. Would anyone be able to explain to me how to make a triangle and possibly a circle? Also is there anyway of doing this without having to create another class?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Vehicle extends JFrame

 {
    final int WIDTH = 900; int HEIGHT = 650;

    Rectangle p1Body = new Rectangle(WIDTH/9,HEIGHT/2, WIDTH/30,WIDTH/30);
    Triangle p1Front = new Triangle(WIDTH/9,HEIGHT/2, WIDTH/30,WIDTH/30);

    Rectangle p2Body = new Rectangle(((WIDTH/9)+((int)((WIDTH/9)*1.5)/2)),(HEIGHT/2)+ 
    (HEIGHT/10),WIDTH/30,WIDTH/30);


public Vehicle()
    {
        super("Radical Racing");
        setSize(WIDTH,HEIGHT);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);

}
public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    super.paint(g);

    g.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    g.fillRect(0,0,WIDTH,HEIGHT);

    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);

    g.fill3DRect(p1Body.x,p1Body.y,p1Body.width,p1Body.height,true);
    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g.fill3D(p1Front.x,p1Front.y,p1Front.width,p1Front.height,true);


    g.setColor(Color.red);

    g.fill3DRect(p2Body.x,p2Body.y,p2Body.width,p2Body.height,true);

}


public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        new Vehicle();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Triangle can be done using Path2D(.Double) circle can be done using Ellipse2D(.Double)

BTW, you might want to think about combining all of these shapes into one using Area - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Area.html. Area is very useful for manipulating shapes & testing if they contain a point etc.

Check out Graphics2D.draw (or fill) (Shape)

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html#draw(java.awt.Shape)